# How to inject/track editor/document meta-data?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to inject custom properties into a document/editor?

For example, I need to edit text from an api endpoint.  It's easy to make the api call and display the data in an editor, then edit the text.  I cannot seem to find a good way to put the meta-data about the text so a post can be made to update the source.  Need to hold information like api-end-point and document id without injecting it into the main editor text.

I have been looking into everything from a CustomDocument/provider to a custome file system provider, but those options seem to be rather complicated for what I need.

```
Example:
api-endpoint: GET /docs

const resp = [{
  name: /docs/note1.txt,
  id: 12345,
  content: 'some text document content'
}, {
  name: /notes/othernote.txt
  id: 54312,
  content: 'special text in another note'
}];

// open a document/editor and display the content of one of the docs from the api reponse
await workspace.openTextDocument({ content: resp[0].content, language: 'text' })
        .then( async (doc) => {
            await window.showTextDocument( doc, { preview: false });
            this.documents.push(doc);
        });
```

Now we have an editor displaying the content but no way to link that content back to the api endpoint (with doc id).  It seems I need to be looking the file system provider so I can inject additional details in to the file stats.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemProvider

Suggestions?

Comment: give an example of what you want to do because this question is vague

Comment: thanks rioV8, I've added more context with example.

Comment: why not keep a record yourself of doc-id and TextDocument

Comment: Sure, that's part of the question.  trying to figure out where/how to store the document id with the text document object.  I can't just extend the TextDocument like a regular class.

Comment: inside your activate function create some kind of data structure to keep this info, or it could also be global to the JS file.